# Server-side public key encryption with browser-side decryption

Tags: encryption, browser, cryptography, public-key-encryption

My application requires certain fields to be encrypted when stored at rest, and allow the user to decrypt them locally in the browser by entering a passphrase. However, these encrypted fields are not entered into the database by the authenticated user himself, but submissions from other people who are supplying the user with private information.

If I stored the passphrase in the database to encrypt new submissions, then anyone who got access to the database would be able to easily decrypt the encrypted information. So, I believe I need to store a public key in the database, encrypt incoming information with the public key, and then serve that encrypted info to the user and let him decrypt it with his passphrase in his browser. (Thus, serverside, we can never decrypt anything.)

I've looked into libraries like [ursa](https://github.com/NodePrime/ursa), but the problem is that the user would have to save his private key. (Correct?) Is there any way that I can do this with a relatively short passphrase instead of a long private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [JSBN](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/) to generate a public-private key pair on the client and use [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) in password encryption mode to encrypt the private key with AES. The encrypted private key and the plaintext public key are then posted to the server and added into the database.

The next time the user gets information encrypted with his/her public key, you send the encrypted information and the encrypted private key to the client/browser. The user can enter the passphrase again to decrypt the private key and then in a second phase decrypt the payload.

Note that this is not absolutely secure because unencrypted traffic (e.g. no TLS) will enable an attacker to extend the html/js to include a data stealing script. Furthermore, the developers of your system can also add such a script whenever they want regardless of TLS or not.